# cocos2d-x Run parent action from child

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I try to write a simple game using cocos2d-x library.

I created class (named Letter) to spawn sprite with random letter as a label and add a listener because I want to catch touch events.
I've a function:

```
listener->onTouchEnded = [=](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    CCLOG("press");
    Letter::touchEvent(touch, event);
};
```

and action:

```
void Letter::touchEvent(cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event)
{
    this->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
    CCLOG("touched MySprite");
}
```

In my Layer I have a function to spawn instance of Letter class:

```
{
    CCLOG("new letter");
    Letter* _letter = Letter::create();

    addChild(_letter, 1);
}
```

And of course in init() i create a one letter:

```
this->createLetter();
```

Now, I want to create action which runs after touch to send some information (int) to my Layer, destroy Sprite and run createLetter(); again.

How can I do this? I tried create CC_CALLBACK_1 and something but I don't have idea what I need to do. :(

I'm not C++ master but I think I've basic knowledge about C++, I'm a system administrator, but I would like to try something net.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User this->getParent() in Latter class to access Layer class from and then call any method written there incuding createLetter() or any new method to pass integer.

## #

```
YourLayerClass* layerObject = (YourLayerClass*)this->getParent();
layerObject->sendData(3);
layerObject->createLetter();
this->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Now I need fix problem withe segmentation fault after removing my sprite. :)

Comment: Can you please explain more about your new issue?

Comment: Yes, of course.
I've modified my code as you suggest. 
This works first time, but second or third time when I click I've got a segmentation faul. I haven't ran gdb to debug this issue yet. If I don't remove object everything will works but I have a lot of sprites. I test this code on Linux. I didn't test on Android.

Thank you for your attention and willingness to help. It's nice.

Comment: Are you reusing the removed sprite? If so then don't cleanup and just remove and retain the object somewhere so it should not be released. Use following for removing:##this->removeFromParentAndCleanup(false);